# Sitio web caido, debido a actualizacion fallida de wordpress

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un sitio web, donde utilizo Wordpress y el contructor de sitios Elementor Pro, el sitio me empezo a dar problemas en los cambios que realizaba en cada pagina, luego no podia actualizar los plugins ni el mismo wordpress, luego de eso mi sitio se vino a bajo, he buscado ayuda en soporte wordpress y no he tenido exito, abajo describo el detalle de los errores que mi sitio.

> Warning: require(/home1/uefycoo1/public_html/xxxxxxx/wp-includes/class-wp-theme-json-data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/uefycoo1/public_html/xxxxxxx/wp-settings.php on line 175
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home1/uefycoo1/public_html/xxxxxxx/wp-includes/class-wp-theme-json-data.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/share/pear') in /home1/uefycoo1/public_html/xxxxxxxx/wp-settings.php on line 175
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function set() on null in /home1/uefycoo1/public_html/xxxxxx/wp-includes/l10n.php:784 Stack trace: #0 /home1/uefycoo1/public_html/xxxxxxx/wp-includes/l10n.php(872): load_textdomain('default', '/home1/uefycoo1...', 'es_MX') #1 /home1/uefycoo1/public_html/xxxxxxx/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(47): load_default_textdomain() #2 [internal function]: WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() #3 {main} thrown in /home1/uefycoo1/public_html/xxxxx/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 784

Comment: Eso puede ser un plugin que quedó en estado no compatible con la versión de wordpress o algo similar. ¿Tienes algún backup de antes de la actualización? Cómo la hiciste?

Comment: si logre subir el backup pero persiste.